# Pandas - Compare positive/negative values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "df":

```
    x  y
0   1  -1
1  -2  -3
2   3   4
3   4   5
4   9   6
```

I am trying to determine what percentage of x and y values are in agreement in terms of being positive or negative. So if x is positive and y is positive, that would be a correct answer. If x and y are both negative, that would be correct. If x and y are different, then it is wrong. Is there a fast way to do this? Ultimately I just want to know what percentage of all rows have a correct answer.

(p.s. there are 1M+ rows in the actual dataframe)

Thank You

Comment: How should we treet rows where one or both values is `0`?

Comment: That situation will not occur in the data I am using, but thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we compare a product of `x*y >= 0` - this should give us `"good"` rows:

```
In [19]: df['x'].mul(df['y']).ge(0)
Out[19]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool


In [20]: df.loc[df['x'].mul(df['y']).ge(0)]
Out[20]:
   x  y
1 -2 -3
2  3  4
3  4  5
4  9  6

In [21]: len(df.loc[df['x'].mul(df['y']).ge(0)])/len(df)
Out[21]: 0.8
```

or as proposed by [@NickilMaveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596652/pandas-compare-positive-negative-values/41596708#comment70396226_41596708) a faster and more "Pandaic" version:

```
In [23]: df['x'].mul(df['y']).ge(0).mean()
Out[23]: 0.80000000000000004
```

the same idea, but this time using [df.eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method:

```
In [27]: df.eval('x * y >= 0').mean()
Out[27]: 0.80000000000000004
```

Comment: `(df.x.mul(df.y).ge(0)).mean()` maybe faster.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, wow, that's smart - i'll add it to the answer! Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if this is the expected behavior, but `x*y >= 0` will clobber any rows containing zero, i.e. (0,0), (0,1), and (0,-1) rows will all be declared as having the same sign.

Comment: @root, it's a good point, but i don't know how OP treats those cases. If they think it's not right, they can easily change `>=` to `>` or `.ge(0)` to `.gt(0)`.

Comment: Unless the convention is that zero is both positive and negative, or that zero doesn't match anything in sign, including itself, both `>=` and `>` will yield incorrect results for rows containing zero.  With `>` zero would match nothing in sign, including itself, i.e. (0,0) will evaluate to False.  With `>=` zero will match everything, as my previous example shows.  I think the usual convention is to have zero as it's own sign, so it only matches itself:  `np.sign([0, -10, 20]) = [0, -1, 1]`.

Comment: @root, stricly speaking, that's correct, but we don't know how OP wants to treet rows where one or both values is/are `0`. So let's wai for an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596652/pandas-compare-positive-negative-values#comment70397746_41596652)...