# How to select rows with only positive or negative values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
                 'x':[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3],
                 'y':[-1, 3, 2, -4, 3, -2],
                 'z':[1 , 1, 5, 2, 1, -1]
```

})
or

```
       x  y  z
    0  1 -1  1
    1  2  3  1
    2  3  2  5
    3 -1 -4  2
    4 -2  3  1
    5 -3 -2 -1
```

The goal is to find the rows that all of their elements have the same (either negative or positive) values.
In this example, it means selecting rows 1, 2, and 5.

I would appreciate any help.
I am aware of this question: [Pandas - Compare positive/negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596652/pandas-compare-positive-negative-values)
but it doesn't address the case where the values are negative.

---

Thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the OR (`|`) to combine conditions:

```
print(df[(df[df.columns] >= 0).all(axis=1) | (df[df.columns] <= 0).all(axis=1)])
```

Prints:

```
   x  y  z
1  2  3  1
2  3  2  5
5 -3 -2 -1
```

Or simpler:

```
print(df[(df >= 0).all(axis=1) | (df <= 0).all(axis=1)])
```

EDIT: As @Erfan stated in the comments, if you want *strictly* negative (without 0), you use `<`:

```
print(df[(df >= 0).all(axis=1) | (df < 0).all(axis=1)])
```

Comment: I guess `df <= 0` should be `df < 0`, besides that I upvoted. You can also use `df[df.ge(0).all(axis=1) | df.lt(0).all(axis=1)]` so you can get rid of the paranthesis.

Comment: @Erfan Oh yes, you're probably right (I was not sure what op means by negative/positive, so I included 0 too). I will edit the answer.

Comment: and you do not need to slice `[df.columns]` essentially you are taking all columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with numpy:

import numpy as np

df[df.columns[df.apply(np.sign).nunique()==1]].T